# What is the name of the opening music in Kingdom Hearts 3D?

Tags: game-music-identification, kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance

What song is playing in the opening from Kingdom Hearts: 3D?

I know this video is fan made, but the music I heard is Kingdom Hearts 3D opening:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the title of the video mentions, the song name is Hikari -KINGDOM Tres Orchestra Intrumental Version-, by Hikaru Utada.

You can listen to it [here (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJH-7u4kAyw) or [here (Spotify)](https://open.spotify.com/track/3usytfZYS960Mp5DCOtZkF?si=dbf6bff4a09b452c).

Comment: i always thought hikari is the name of the orchestra :D

Comment: This brings back memories. I heard this track live at a [Video Games Live](https://www.videogameslive.com/) concert, performed by a full orchestra. Probably one of the most beautiful things I've ever heard